# .NET detailed compilation log or information

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm facing a compilation error which is not showing much details. It's not pointing to any particular line of code.

[image: screenshot]

**Is there any compilation log file where I can find some detailed info?**

*I'm not asking about a solution of this particular problem, but a general information about any log file where I can find details about the compilation process.*

I'm using VS 2012. The error appears only when MvcBuildViews option is on.

Comment: Could you post the compiler output?

Comment: What _does_ it show?

Comment: Error 122 Could not load file or assembly 'IBM.Data.DB2.ASP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. somePath\ASPNETCOMPILER SomeProjectName

BUT it's not my question. I'm asking in general, how to debug this scenario.

Comment: I"m not sure what more you could ask for. The message is as verbose as it could be.

Comment: No it's not. In the column file it shows "ASPNETCOMPILER". It's not a file in my project.

Comment: You are mixing 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs...

Comment: To answer actual question, try View -> Output.

Comment: The compiler falls over *before* it can start compiling the code.  So of course there is no line number.

Comment: This can help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Phate01 That's VERY interesting. Thank you so much! I think you could post an answer with small description of changing build output verbosity. It's exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: When it comes to the particular problem - I've changed version of IBM's DLL and it has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643(v=vs.110).aspx

> - To change the verbosity level of log data On the menu bar, choose **Tools, Options.**
> - On the **Projects and Solutions page**, choose the **Build
>     and Run** page.
> - In the **MSBuild project build output verbosity list**,
>     choose one of the following values, and then choose the **OK** button.